# Aggregating splitted records

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an issue related with splitted messages.
My flexcube oracle table has a field(column) called 'Message' that has xml code inside, and this message is related with a number account (another column), ie, there is a message for each number account.

The problem is that the message is splitted in two or three records (with the same number account) when the message is too large. 
Now I have to merge those message pieces for each number account to return the complete message to a query that I asked to my table.
My 'Message' column has the type CLOB.

I started using ListAgg() function but there is a size problem (4000 char).
I hope I'm being clear. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this article about string aggregation, maybe one of the techniques will suit you?

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#specific_function

Also, there is a possibilty to write a user-defined analytic function - maybe you would consider writing an analytic function of your own, which would yield a CLOB result (not sure if CLOB is an option here, but you could try). More on that topic here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dciaggfns.htm

**Edit**: Well, have you even tried googling it? Here is what I found and it seems to work:

```
SELECT
   DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
    EXTRACT(
      xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?><document>' || XMLAGG(XMLTYPE('<V>' || DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(message)|| '</V>')).getclobval()||'</document>'),
      '/document/V/text()').getclobval(), 1) AS data_value
FROM 
   account_messages
GROUP BY
   account_no;
```

I am not the author, the code is from: http://sonra.io/listagg-with-clob-string-aggregation-exceeding-4000-characters-with-xmlagg/

Comment: When I said "aggregate" I meant "concatenate".What I want to do is to concatenate long character expressions. The problem is that the expressions are too large (more than 4000 char) and the ListAgg() function does not work. Have you a possible solution?